# git: how to set up cross-platform .gitconfig with core.sshcommand?

Tags: git

I keep my .gitconfig in a repo, and use it across Windows, Linux and MacOS. Recently I've set it up to work with the system OpenSSH on Windows 11. That requires this setting:

```
[core]
  sshcommand=C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe
```

I'd like to keep my gitconfig cross-platform so of course I don't want to check that in as it is. I know I could write a two-line shell script and point to that as `core.sshcommand` but I'm wondering if via some shell magic I could keep it all in my `.gitconfig`. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of setting `core.sshcommand` in `.gitconfig` set OS-dependent environment variable [`GIT_SSH` or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode).

Comment: Thanks! If you make that an answer I'll accept it. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `core.sshcommand` in a single `.gitconfig` set OS-dependent environment variable [`GIT_SSH` or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode) in your OS and shell dependent initialization files.

They have different purpose: `GIT_SSH` must point to a program that is directly executed, the value cannot contain parameters to the program; `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` can contain the entire command line — a program with parameters — the value is passed to a shell to evaluate.